# Excel - can the round criteria be modified?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, rounding

In the school i work they have its "own qualification round criteria", if decimal is < .7 round down, otherwise round up. Example: a 89.6 will be rounded to 89; and 91.7 to 92 (why? we'll never know).
Excel has the rounding rule of >=.5 round up. Is there some function that allow to modify that criteria?

Comment: No. You can write your own VBA code that will do this sort of absurd rounding. Make sure that whoever came up with that criteria for rounding is aware that it is going to cause all sorts of problems arriving at proper totals when doing any sort of mathematical operations requiring any accuracy, such as a simple sum.

Comment: Assuming your original number is in `A1` then you can use `=ROUND(A1-0.2,0)`

Comment: Alternatively to the previous comment, depending on how you want to handle negative numbers (such as `-0.3`), you may prefer `=ROUNDDOWN(A1+0.3,0)`

Comment: @KenWhite ik its completly stupid, that happen when the same kind of ppl are the bosses, the ones who dont listen anythig from anyone.

Comment: @SpectralInstance `=ROUND(A1-0.2,0)` do the trick, post it as an answer so i can accept it.

Comment: Yes, I've worked for this sort of bosses. Be ready when they come back and yell at you because things aren't adding up right - that's what usually happened to me. Note that the comment from @SpectralInstance doesn't actually answer your question (although it works around your problem). The question you asked is whether Excel's ROUND() function could be changed, and it cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your numbers are in the `A` column then you can use the formula `=ROUND(A1-0.2,0)` and copy down:-
[image]